# Is there anyway to determine what IAM permissions I actually need for a CloudFormation template?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

Just wondering whats the best practice for determining what permissions I should give for my CloudFormation template?

After some time of trying to give the minimal permissions it require, I find that thats really time consuming and error prone. I note that depending on the state of my stack, really new vs some updates vs delete, I will need different permissions.

I guess, it should be possible for there to be some parser that given a CloudFormation template can determine the minimum set of permissions it require?

Maybe I can give `ec2:*` access to resources tagged `Cost Center: My Project Name`? Is this ok? But I wonder what happens when I change my project name for example?

Alternatively, isit ok to assume its ok to give say `ec2:*` access based on the assumption the CloudFormation parts is usually only executed off CodeCommit/Github/CodePipeline and its not something that is likely to be public/easy to hack? --- Tho this sounds like a flawed statement to me ...

Comment: I discussed this with multiple AWS engineers at a conference and their answer was: "not really". Best way is to assign nothing and see what errors it throws.

Comment: @Exelian omg ... have been doing that like for nearly 2 days already ... and I didnt even give all access ... I just read through the list and try to select only those I think I need ... even then I took so long ...

Comment: @JiewMeng did you ever find a solution to this that you were happy with?

Answer (score 4):

In the short term, you can use [aws-leastprivilege](https://github.com/iann0036/aws-leastprivilege). [But it doesn't support every resource type](https://github.com/iann0036/aws-leastprivilege/tree/master/cfnlp/mappings).

For the long term: [as mentioned in this 2019 re:invent talk](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=pRGF7TidkNM&feature=youtu.be&t=2786), CloudFormation is working towards open sourcing and migrating most of its resource types to a new public [resource schema](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-resource-schema). One of the benefits of this is that you'll be able to see  the permissions required to perform each operation.

E.g. for [AWS::ImageBuilder::Image](https://github.com/aws-cloudformation/aws-cloudformation-resource-providers-imagebuilder/tree/master/image), the schema says

```
    "handlers": {
        "create": {
            "permissions": [
                "iam:GetRole",
                "imagebuilder:GetImageRecipe",
                "imagebuilder:GetInfrastructureConfiguration",
                "imagebuilder:GetDistributionConfiguration",
                "imagebuilder:GetImage",
                "imagebuilder:CreateImage",
                "imagebuilder:TagResource"
            ]
        },
        "read": {
            "permissions": [
                "imagebuilder:GetImage"
            ]
        },
        "delete": {
            "permissions": [
                "imagebuilder:GetImage",
                "imagebuilder:DeleteImage",
                "imagebuilder:UnTagResource"
            ]
        },
        "list": {
            "permissions": [
                "imagebuilder:ListImages"
            ]
        }
    }
```