# How to create a minimal and complete IAM roles/permissions given requirements?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam

IAM gives developers controls to limit which users can access specific services, the kinds of action they can perform, and which resources are available (VMs, database instances, etc).

Given a list of resources, API calls, and services used, how does one go about creating a minimal (but sufficiently free) IAM role or user for this project?

---

Inspired by Exelian's reponse to Jiew Meng in [Is there anyway to determine what IAM permissions I actually need for a CloudFormation template?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/51596254/4562156):

> Jiew Meng: "I guess, it should be possible for there to be some parser that given a CloudFormation template can determine the minimum set of permissions it"
>
> Exelian: "I discussed this with multiple AWS engineers at a conference and their answer was: "not really". Best way is to assign nothing and see what errors it throws."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

"Not really" still applies. You have to hand-craft your roles and policies and test them. But, there are some tools to help:

- [AWS Policy Generator](https://awspolicygen.s3.amazonaws.com/policygen.html) and [AWS Identity and Access Management Template Snippets](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/quickref-iam.html) to get you started.
- [Complete AWS IAM Reference](https://iam.cloudonaut.io/) to check the fine detail.
- Then, peer review and testing.