# Is there a tool that will tell me what permissions will be required to create a Cloudformation template?

Tags: permissions, aws-cloudformation

My team is attempting to move towards templatization of our services and their infrastructure.

We have found it to be extremely time-consuming to determine the set of permissions required to execute or update a given Cloudformation template. Our process is:

1. Create a user with permissions `cloudformation:CreateStack` and/or `cloudformation:UpdateStack`
2. Have that user attempt to create/update the specified stack
3. Observe which missing permission caused the stack operation to fail
4. Add that permission to the user
5. Go to 2.

The alternative to this would be to create a "God User" who has unlimited permissions and have that user execute the create/update - which seems to violate the [Principle Of Least Privilege](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Principle_of_least_privilege)

Alternatively, is there a tool that can list "what permissions have been exercised by a given user in the past N minutes?". If such a tool existed, we could create the "God User", have them execute the template, and then create a more limited-scope user that has precisely the permissions that the God User had used.

Comment: This looks like a duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51596254/is-there-anyway-to-determine-what-iam-permissions-i-actually-need-for-a-cloudfor

Answer (score 3):

There is no simple way/tool to do this.

Here are a couple of approaches you can try-

1. Using an User that has Admin priviledges, create the Stack. Once done, wait for 15-20 minutes for CloudTrail to populate. Now in CloudTrail list the API calls made by the 'Event Source' - 'cloudformation.amazonaws.com'. That should be roughly all the API calls required. There can be a few more calls required, for other operations as you keep on adding functionalities to the Resources. Again, you would need to figure that out this way.
2. Create a [CFN service role](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSCloudFormation/latest/UserGuide/using-iam-servicerole.html) , and add admin privileges to this Role. Use this Role to create/update/delete the Stacks. Allow the IAM users only iam:PassRole and cloudformation:* . However, users will be able to create different resources using CFN.
3. Use Service Catalog and create Products. Service Catalog Products are CFN Templates which can be launched by a specific user/Role/Group. The user does not need permission to create/modify the Resources in a Stack/Product. Also the end user cannot change the Product to add more Resources. Here's a great video that explains this stuff : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=A9kKy6WhqVA

Hope this helps...