# Is there a way to quickly determine ALL the permissions needed by cloudformation?

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation, amazon-iam

When I'm trying to get away from mickey mouse permissions, *.*, and give only the least necessary, I find that I have to create my stack, see what failed, delete it, create it, delete it, etc etc ad nauseum.

Is there a way to quickly verify all of the permissions that a cloudformation template will need?

I have tried running it with *.* and seeing what all it uses in cloudtrail, but for some reason that didn't give me all of them.

This question:
[Is there anyway to determine what IAM permissions I actually need for a CloudFormation template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51596254/is-there-anyway-to-determine-what-iam-permissions-i-actually-need-for-a-cloudfor)

Is a year and a half old which is lifetimes in software dev, so there may be a solution now.

Comment: One option is to deploy the resources manually via the management console and use [Console Recorder for AWS](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/console-recorder-for-aws/ganlhgooidfbijjidcpkeaohjnkeicba?hl=en) to record the actions. It can also provide a policy with necessary permissions.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there anyway to determine what IAM permissions I actually need for a CloudFormation template?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51596254/is-there-anyway-to-determine-what-iam-permissions-i-actually-need-for-a-cloudfor)